# How to install php-mime-mail-parser on my ISP server?

Tags: php, parsing, mime-mail

It is not clear how I should install php-mime-mail-parser on my web server (at my ISP).
I was using mime-parser from M Lemos but that class is not php 7 compliant so I have to find another option.  In the latest case, I simply copied the php files on my server.  Is it not the same with php-mime-mail-parser?  I would also appreciate to find working example to adapt my code as easy as possible.